# A 32-bit version of the TEA algorithm

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I need a sequence of unique alpha-numeric serial numbers that are random, and have decided to use TEA (the Tiny Encryption Algorithm) since it's quick, elegant and efficient. However, I've only found 64-bit implementations which yield numbers that are too long: a 32-bit number would be far preferable. I'd like to use a 32-bit version of TEA, but it's unlikely that one exists.

My problem, of course, is that I've no idea HOW it works - how such a convoluted sequence of manipulations yields a code that can be input to a reversed algorithm to regain the original. It's fascinating, certainly, but at this stage I'd settle for a quick answer rather than the needed insights.

For those interested, the encrypt/decrypt algo's are:

```
while(n-->0) {
    sum += delta;
    y += (z << 4)+a ^ z+sum ^ (z >> 5)+b;
    z += (y << 4)+c ^ y+sum ^ (y >> 5)+d;
}

while(n-->0) {
    z -= (y << 4)+c ^ y+sum ^ (y >> 5)+d;
    y -= (z << 4)+a ^ z+sum ^ (z >> 5)+b;
    sum -= delta;
}
```

I've written a quick hack that prints out the first ten numbers, so it's working (happy to post it if anyone's interested - 60 lines), but if anyone can either point me to a 32-bit version or explain the magic of its operation I'd be forever grateful.

Answer (score 3):

In each encryption round:

1. `sum+=delta`.  This can be easily reversed by `sum-=delta`
2. `y+=f(z,sum)`, i.e., what you add to `y` is a function of `z` and `sum` only.  Since `z` and `sum` are unchanged, this can be easily reversed by `sum-=f(z,sum)`
3. `z+=g(y,sum)`.  what you add to `z` is a function of `y` and `sum` only. Since `y` and `sum` are unchanged, this can be easily reversed by `z-=g(y,sum)`

This simple way of ensuring that the cipher is reversible is obviously inspired by the Feistel structure that is used in many modern block ciphers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes, can nearly see it now. I don't use C much, and at first took the caret '^' to mean exponentiation, which had me sorely bemused - how do you recover the lost stuff?

Comment: @vitency there shouldn't be any lost stuff

Comment: "there shouldn't be any lost stuff" - which is what had me puzzled!